# When is there scheduled downtime/weekly maintenance?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Other MMOs I've played in the past (Star Wars Galaxies, EverQuest 2, World of Warcraft) had a specific time each week that they took their servers down for maintenance.

Does SWTOR have weekly scheduled maintenance periods?

Comment: Why are these maintenance periods necessarily? I only play FFXI and it doesn't happen on there.

Comment: @Zeno Database maintenance and tuning, mostly.

Comment: @Zeno http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19544/what-is-the-purpose-of-mmo-maintenance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, although [it appears to be more of a rough schedule](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=28168):

> Generally speaking we are aiming to limit our scheduled maintenance period to once a week, on Tuesdays. We are aiming for this weekly maintenance period to take place in an off-peak time for both North American and European players. We are also aiming to inform players of the precise duration of any weekly maintenance period at least 24 hours before the maintenance begins.

3AM EST is the normal maintenance time, so the European servers go down at 8AM GMT and so on.

Comment: This weeks was the same for America and Europe tho... like 3 am America 10am Europe ... boooh

Answer (score -1):

Yes it will early Tuesday morning till late morning. However they are doing minor shut downs in the early hours when they need to fix things that they feel can't wait till the set time. I have been kicked off any where from 1 am to 4am. Cst throu out this last week  and the down time has vairyed. But after the game has been input for a bit they will limit down time to the set Tuesday hours

Answer (score -1):

In europe is during the day. In my time zone it is 11am-5pm :-(

Comment: What timezone are you in?